# Implementation of Code Snippet toolbar in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement in Cocoa a library like in Xcode with drag and drop similar to the code snippets library? I'd like to implement a library which would drag pre-defined text into a view. My thought was to simply implement an NSTableView with drag and drop. Does anyone have any other suggestions or thoughts as to how to implement?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the Drag & Drop Programming guid and about paste boards as well as drag & drop support in NSTableView.

It's not just a little and you'll need to take it step by step.

The basic gist is that you begin a drag from your table view.
This in code amounts to putting something on the pasteboard. (either actual content or promising content for if a drop is completed.)
Then the receiving app's view reads the pasteboard for pasteboard types that it can handle.
For an NSTextView that's pretty much automatic if you've put plain text on the pasteboard.